# Передаю bunlde в активити но выдает пустой bundle

Tags: java, android

Хочу открывать картинки в актвити из фрагмента передаю путь к картинке

```
public void openImage(String image) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullscreenActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("image", image);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

и в активити хочу получить путь который я засунул в Bundle

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        loge("savedinstance == null");
    }
    String image  = savedInstanceState.getString("image");
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(image));

}
```

выходит так что bundle null и соответственно выдает exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы используете не тот `Bundle`. Чтобы получить ваш `"image"` в `onCreate` обратно, надо так:

```
String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
```

[Bundle savedInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) предназначен совсем не для того. Вас вообще его название не смущает?

Вообще не стоит использовать Bundle для этого, сделайте просто

```
intent.putExtra("image", image);
```